# Border coloring for breadcrump items

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create  a breadcrumb that looks like this [image: breadcrumb]

So far I made some good progress .But I am no able to add these border colors to `<li>` items. How can I do this ? Here is what I have done till now.

```css
#breadcrumbs{
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
  }

  #breadcrumbs li{
    float: left;
    margin: 0 .3em 0 1em;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
  }

  #breadcrumbs a{
    background: #eef6f8;
    padding: .4em 1em;
    float: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5);
    position: relative;
  }

  #breadcrumbs > li.active > a{
    background:#00305e;
    color: #fff;
  }

  #breadcrumbs a:hover{
    background: #99db76;
  }

  #breadcrumbs a::before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -1.5em;
    border-width: 1.5em 0 1.5em 1em;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #eef6f8 #eef6f8 #eef6f8 transparent;
    left: -1em;
  }

  #breadcrumbs li:first-child  a::before{
border-color:#eef6f8;
  }
  #breadcrumbs li.active > a::after{
    border-left: 1em solid #00305e;
  }

  #breadcrumbs li.active:first-child  >  a::before{
    border-color:#00305e;
      }

  #breadcrumbs a:hover::before{
    border-color: #99db76 #99db76 #99db76 transparent;
  }

  #breadcrumbs a::after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -1.5em;
    border-top: 1.5em solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 1.5em solid transparent;
    border-left: 1em solid #eef6f8;
    right: -1em;
  }

  

  #breadcrumbs a:hover::after{
    border-left-color: #99db76;
  }

  #breadcrumbs .current,
  #breadcrumbs .current:hover{
    font-weight: bold;
    background: none;
  }

  #breadcrumbs .current::after,
  #breadcrumbs .current::before{
    content: normal;
  }
```

```html
<head>
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body style="background-color:wheat">
<div class="crumbs-menu">
  <ul id="breadcrumbs">
      <li class="active"><a href="">Medical</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Dental</a></li>
           <li><a href="">Vision</a></li>
            </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple drop-shadow filter can do the job here without changing your code:

```css
#breadcrumbs {
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

#breadcrumbs li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 .3em 0 1em;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

#breadcrumbs a {
  background: #eef6f8;
  padding: .4em 1em;
  float: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  position: relative;
  filter:drop-shadow(2px 0px 0px red); /* added (2px of red border) */
}

#breadcrumbs>li.active>a {
  background: #00305e;
  color: #fff;
}

#breadcrumbs a:hover {
  background: #99db76;
}

#breadcrumbs a::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -1.5em;
  border-width: 1.5em 0 1.5em 1em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #eef6f8 #eef6f8 #eef6f8 transparent;
  left: -1em;
}

#breadcrumbs li:first-child a::before {
  border-color: #eef6f8;
}

#breadcrumbs li.active>a::after {
  border-left: 1em solid #00305e;
}

#breadcrumbs li.active:first-child>a::before {
  border-color: #00305e;
}

#breadcrumbs a:hover::before {
  border-color: #99db76 #99db76 #99db76 transparent;
}

#breadcrumbs a::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -1.5em;
  border-top: 1.5em solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 1.5em solid transparent;
  border-left: 1em solid #eef6f8;
  right: -1em;
}

#breadcrumbs a:hover::after {
  border-left-color: #99db76;
}

#breadcrumbs .current,
#breadcrumbs .current:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
  background: none;
}

#breadcrumbs .current::after,
#breadcrumbs .current::before {
  content: normal;
}
```

```html
<body style="background-color:wheat">
  <div class="crumbs-menu">
    <ul id="breadcrumbs">
      <li class="active"><a href="">Medical</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Dental</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Vision</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can add an extra `span` element for the right arrow. I would do it like this.

```html
<ul id="breadcrumbs">
    <li class="active">
        <a href="">Medical</a>
        <span class="right-arrow"></span>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="">Dental</a>
        <span class="right-arrow"></span>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="">Vision</a>
        <span class="right-arrow"></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Using `clip-path`, I would create the 2 shapes for right arrows with different colors — one that will match the primary color of the breadcrump and a second one to act as the border effect.

*Learn more about `clip-path` on [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path). Or if you're visual learner, play [here](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/).*

```css
#breadcrumbs li:not(.active) a:hover + .right-arrow {
    --primary-color: #99db76;
}

.active .right-arrow {
    --primary-color: #00305e;
    --secondary-color: green;
}

.right-arrow {
    --polygon: polygon(0 0, 5px 0, 100% 50%, 5px 100%, 0 100%);
    --primary-color: #eef6f8;
    --secondary-color: #00305e;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -1em;
    height: 100%;
    width: 1em;
}

.right-arrow::after {
    content: "";
    height: inherit;
    width: inherit;
    position: absolute;
    left: -3px;
    background-color: var(--primary-color);
    clip-path: var(--polygon);
}

.right-arrow::before {
    content: "";
    height: inherit;
    width: inherit;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: var(--secondary-color);
    clip-path: var(--polygon);
}
```

```css
#breadcrumbs {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

#breadcrumbs li {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0.3em 0 1em;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

#breadcrumbs a {
  background: #eef6f8;
  padding: 0.4em 1em;
  float: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  position: relative;
}

#breadcrumbs>li.active>a {
  background: #00305e;
  color: #fff;
}

#breadcrumbs a:hover {
  background: #99db76;
}

#breadcrumbs a::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -1.5em;
  border-width: 1.5em 0 1.5em 1em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #eef6f8 #eef6f8 #eef6f8 transparent;
  left: -1em;
}

#breadcrumbs li:first-child a::before {
  border-color: #eef6f8;
}

#breadcrumbs li.active>a::after {
  border-left: 1em solid #00305e;
}

#breadcrumbs li.active:first-child>a::before {
  border-color: #00305e;
}

#breadcrumbs a:hover::before {
  border-color: #99db76 #99db76 #99db76 transparent;
}

#breadcrumbs li:not(.active) a:hover+.right-arrow {
  --primary-color: #99db76;
}

.active .right-arrow {
  --primary-color: #00305e;
  --secondary-color: green;
}

.right-arrow {
  --polygon: polygon(0 0, 5px 0, 100% 50%, 5px 100%, 0 100%);
  --primary-color: #eef6f8;
  --secondary-color: #00305e;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -1em;
  height: 100%;
  width: 1em;
}

.right-arrow::after {
  content: "";
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  left: -3px;
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
  clip-path: var(--polygon);
}

.right-arrow::before {
  content: "";
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: var(--secondary-color);
  clip-path: var(--polygon);
}

#breadcrumbs a:hover::after {
  border-left-color: #99db76;
}

#breadcrumbs .current,
#breadcrumbs .current:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
  background: none;
}

#breadcrumbs .current::after,
#breadcrumbs .current::before {
  content: normal;
}
```

```html
<body style="background-color: wheat;">
  <div class="crumbs-menu">
    <ul id="breadcrumbs">
      <li class="active">
        <a href="">Medical</a>
        <span class="right-arrow"></span>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="">Dental</a>
        <span class="right-arrow"></span>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="">Vision</a>
        <span class="right-arrow"></span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```